# How can I use generics type with Infragistics XamDataTree

Tags: infragistics

I would like to use generic data structure say "INode" as the underlying data source  for XamDataTree, how can I specify the generic type wiht TargetTypeName attribute of NodeLayout? As long as I can specify non-generic type, the XamDataTree works ok, but not with generic type?

I have tried setting TargetTypeName as below, but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Infragistics Support](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/81150.aspx), XamDataTree does not support generics